# Create a query for pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot-table

I have this query and I want to create a pivot table. I already saw some samples  but I didn't understand very well.

```
SELECT        Users.FullName, Speciality.Shortname, COUNT(1) AS contador
FROM            DoctorsVisits INNER JOIN
                         Speciality ON DoctorsVisits.SpecialityId = Speciality.SpecialityId INNER JOIN
                         VisitType ON DoctorsVisits.VisitTypeId = VisitType.VisitTypeId INNER JOIN
                         Users ON DoctorsVisits.UserId = Users.UserId
WHERE        (MONTH(DoctorsVisits.VisitDate) = @month) AND (YEAR(DoctorsVisits.VisitDate) = @year)
GROUP BY Speciality.Shortname, Users.FullName
```

My idea is to put Speciality.Shortname on the columns, Users.FullName in the Rows and Count(1) as contador as cross value inside table. I am using VS 2010 table adapter

I made one like this

ACS and CIR are rows from column Shortname on Speciality table

```
SELECT * FROM
( 
SELECT        Speciality.Shortname, Users.FullName, COUNT(1) AS contador
FROM            DoctorsVisits INNER JOIN
                         Speciality ON DoctorsVisits.SpecialityId = Speciality.SpecialityId INNER JOIN
                         VisitType ON DoctorsVisits.VisitTypeId = VisitType.VisitTypeId INNER JOIN
                         Users ON DoctorsVisits.UserId = Users.UserId
)  j
PIVOT 
(
SUM(contador) 
FOR Shortname 
IN 
(
[ACS],[CIR]
) 
) PivotTable
```

Comment: Do you know what shortnames you are concerned about ahead of time?  That is, before you write your pivot query, do you have a list of shortnames that you are concerned with?  If yes, then you can use a regular-old-pivot query.  If no, then you will need to build a dynamic pivot query.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I can do with the information that you provided is point you to an article that does a good job walking you through [how to build a dynamic pivot query](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/).  Providing you with a more precise answer would require more information about your data and your requirements.  Check out the article, it does a good job, I think.

EDIT:
Okay, this sample code should walk you through setting up your PIVOT.  Remember that this is a static pivot.  If you don't want to manually list out a hundred different specialties, you'll need to start with this and build a dynamic pivot.  The only difference between the two is that with a dynamic pivot, you're putting your "dynamically" building your SQL query in a variable and then executing the variable.

One more thing... My sample code leaves out the VisitType table.  I'm making the assumption that there is a foreign-key constraint between DoctorsVisits and VisitType.  If so, then this INNER JOIN has no effect on the query except to slow it down a bit.  So I left it out.  You can feel free to add it back if you need to.

```
use tempdb
GO
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Users          TABLE(UserID int, FullName varchar(50));
DECLARE @Specialty      TABLE(SpecialtyID int, ShortName varchar(50));
DECLARE @DoctorsVisits  TABLE(UserID int, VisitTypeID int, SpecialtyID int, visitDate DateTime);
--DECLARE @VisitType        TABLE(VisitTypeID int); -- NOT USED

INSERT @Users VALUES (1, 'Jim Bob');
INSERT @Users VALUES (2, 'Bobbie Joe');
INSERT @Users VALUES (3, 'Bubba');
INSERT @Users VALUES (4, 'Mike');

INSERT @Specialty VALUES (1, 'Pediatrics');
INSERT @Specialty VALUES (2, 'Obstetrics');
INSERT @Specialty VALUES (3, 'Cardiology');
INSERT @Specialty VALUES (4, 'Immunology');

INSERT @DoctorsVisits VALUES (1, 0, 4, '1/1/2014');
INSERT @DoctorsVisits VALUES (1, 0, 4, '3/3/2014');
INSERT @DoctorsVisits VALUES (1, 0, 3, '12/12/2014');
INSERT @DoctorsVisits VALUES (2, 0, 1, '1/1/2014');
INSERT @DoctorsVisits VALUES (2, 0, 1, '4/4/2014');
INSERT @DoctorsVisits VALUES (2, 0, 1, '10/10/2014');
INSERT @DoctorsVisits VALUES (2, 0, 1, '1/11/2015');
INSERT @DoctorsVisits VALUES (2, 0, 2, '7/7/2014');
INSERT @DoctorsVisits VALUES (2, 0, 2, '8/8/2014');
INSERT @DoctorsVisits VALUES (2, 0, 2, '9/9/2014');
INSERT @DoctorsVisits VALUES (3, 0, 3, '1/11/2013');
INSERT @DoctorsVisits VALUES (3, 0, 3, '1/11/2014');
INSERT @DoctorsVisits VALUES (3, 0, 3, '1/11/2015');
INSERT @DoctorsVisits VALUES (4, 0, 3, '10/10/2014');

SET NOCOUNT OFF;

SELECT FullName, [Pediatrics], [Cardiology], [Obstetrics]
FROM ( 
    SELECT  S.Shortname, U.FullName, 1 as contador
    FROM    @DoctorsVisits D INNER JOIN
            @Specialty S ON D.SpecialtyID = S.SpecialtyID INNER JOIN
            @Users U ON D.UserId = U.UserId
)  SourceTable
PIVOT 
(
SUM(contador) 
FOR Shortname IN ([Pediatrics], [Cardiology], [Obstetrics]) 
) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: I updated my question, thank you for your answer, it helped but I could not do it anyway.. can you see if it is right?

Answer (score 0):

I did it.. this one works

```
SELECT        FullName as Name,[CIR],[CAR]
FROM            (SELECT        Users.FullName, Speciality.Shortname, COUNT(1) AS contar
                          FROM DoctorsVisits INNER JOIN
                          Users ON DoctorsVisits.UserId = Users.UserId INNER JOIN
                          Speciality ON DoctorsVisits.SpecialityId = Speciality.SpecialityId INNER JOIN
                          VisitType ON DoctorsVisits.VisitTypeId = VisitType.VisitTypeId 
                          WHERE (DoctorsVisits.EnterpriseId = 48) AND (Month(DoctorsVisits.VisitDate) = @mes) AND (Year(DoctorsVisits.VisitDate) = @ano) 
                          GROUP BY Users.FullName, Speciality.Shortname)as ps
                          PIVOT (COUNT(contar) FOR Shortname IN ([CIR], [CAR])) pvt
```